# How to record video with audio of a particular UIView not full screen in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I am using camera preview with `AVFoundation` on a `UIView` and also perform some action(i.e. animation, effects) on that `UIView` and I want to record that particular `UIView` activity with audio from microphone or audio from own app.